# How can I combine the two matrix in this way?

Tags: matlab

For example, I define matrix

```
A = ones(2,2,2)
```

and

```
B = ones(2,2,2)
```

I wish to combine A and B to form a new matrix C so that the size of C is 2,2,4 and `C(:,:,1:2) = A` and `C(:,:,3:4)=B`

How may I do it? I tried `C = [A B]` or `C = [A,B]` but none of them works

Comment: I would use the "cat" command. Let me know if this works: `>> C = cat(DIM,A,B);` In other words, you are concatenating matrices A and B along any dimension you want. Since A and B are 3D, DIM would be 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: reshape works as well: `C=reshape([reshape(A,[4,2]) reshape(B,[4,2])],[2,2,4])`